# Имею ли я права на работу с сохраненной музыкой ВКонтакте?

Tags: android

Решил написать приложение, в котором сохраненная музыка ВКонтакте будет копироваться на  SD-карту. Это не запрещено? Модерация в Google Play пропустит? Сам ВКонтакте не запрещает? Слышал, что сейчас там какие-то проблемы с музыкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стримить музыку ты уже не сможешь, API закрыли и теперь вместо музыки проигрывается аудиозапись с призывом скачать официальное приложение. Если сохраненная музыка хранится в открытом виде (во внешнем хранилище), то думаю никаких проблем не будет. Но если ты пытаешься ее достать из внутреннего хранилища (через root права), то вполне можно ожидать жалобу в Google Play от ВКонтакте, если они это заметят.

Comment: Нет, музыка лежит в памяти телефона, в скрытой папке `sdcard/.vkontakte/cache/audio и представляет собой файлы без разрешения. Значит, можно?

Comment: Ну все, что хранится на SD карте с точки зрения Android считается открытым :) Поэтому я считаю, что можно, но как это с их точки зрения - я не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо :) Не на карте памяти а во внутренней

Comment: Внутренняя память тоже может быть внешним хранилищем (как в Nexus 5). Это не про физический уровень, а логический. Внешняя память это то, что могут увидеть все приложения, а внутренняя память это то, что не могут увидеть другие приложения, разве только с рутом. Так вот, если на внешней, то все ок, а если во внутренней будет и приложение будет вытягивать это с помощью рута - вот тут уже могут появится претензии.

Comment: Ну значит все будет хорошо. Спасибо ещё раз

Comment: Кстати насчёт призыва. Нет ничего такого. И вк кофе и мп3 мод норм её стримят